# Unable to insert data into table (Python3, mysql, discord.py)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, discord.py

So here is my code

````
            sqleee = f"INSERT INTO welcome(guild_id, channel_id) VALUES({ctx.guild.id}, {channel.id})"
            cursor.execute(sqleee)
            db.commit()```
````

Comment: Yes. It is your code

Comment: kacperku tego sie domyslilem

Comment: No i co w związku z tym?